# How to pass an integer through an instance method and add that with an instance variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, parameter-passing, instance-variables

I was trying to add the parameter `bonus` (which will take an integer) with the instance variable `self.pay` and wanted to print that final payment with the worker's name. But, I could not print that added total payment

I want to call the method `rise()` instead of returning anything from it, but I am confused how I can call that and pass an integer number.

```
class Information:
    def __init__(self,first,last,pay):

        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay


    def rise(self,int(bonus)):
        self.pay = self.pay + bonus

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s and %s and has a balance of %s" % (self.first,self.last,self.pay)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    emp1 = Information("tom","jerry",999)
    print (emp1)
```

Comment: `emp1.rise(x)`  where `x` is the bonus value. Do it after `emp1 = Information("tom","jerry",999)`. and don't use `int` in `def`, it will result in error

Comment: You cannot have a call to `int()` in the function definition. You could do the conversion to an `int` _inside_ the method body, or use [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). That's the only change you need to make. Then `emp1.rise(1000); `print(emp1)` will give the result you expect

Comment: @mmdud: On a lighter note, the english word "raise" is more appropriate than the word "rise", to name your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Information:
    def __init__(self,first,last,pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay

    def raise_salary(self, bonus):
        self.pay += int(bonus) # exception if bonus cannot be casted

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s and %s and has a balance of %s" % (self.first,self.last,self.pay)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    emp1 = Information("tom", "jerry", 999)
    print(emp1)
    emp1.raise_salary('1000') # or just emp1.raise(1000)
    print(emp1)
```

Comment: your solution is really helpful, thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with below code.

I updated **def rise(self,int(bonus)):** to **def rise(self,bonus):**

```
class Information:
    def __init__(self,first,last,pay):

        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay


    def rise(self,bonus):
        self.pay = self.pay + bonus

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s and %s and has a balance of %s" % (self.first,self.last,self.pay)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    emp1 = Information("tom","jerry",999)
    emp1.rise(89)
    print (emp1)
```